# How to call a javascript function with string arrays

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

Can anyone please tell me how to call javascript function with string arrays as argument and how to use this arrays in the called function.
Here is my code:

C#  Code

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    array1[i] = dt.Rows[i]["FieldName"].ToString();
    array2[i] = dt.Rows[i]["FieldValue"].ToString();
}
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"Javascript", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction('" + count + "','" + array1 + "','" + array2 + "');</script>");
```

JavaScript

```
function myFunction(cnt, arr1, arr2)
{
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        alert("fname" + arr1[i] + " :fvalue " + arr2[i] + " :count:" + cnt);
    }
}
```

any syntax error in passing array variables.

Comment: the arr1 and arr2 is string in your javascript function. so if you do arr1[i], you actually will get characters I think. For what you want, I think you can split the arr1 and arr2 and use it as an array accordingly.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Regard the C#-Code. In `cnt` in the JavaScript-Code is the `count`-variable from C#-Code stored. So it already is the count, not the array itself.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald is right.. just add(.length) after cnt

Comment: @PatrikEckebrecht I have no idea about C# tbh, was just the first thing I noticed when looking at the JS

Comment: @GeoffreyMureithi Absolutely okay, but it's obvious - for anyone who knows C-Style-languages - that `count` is an number-type, and that `cnt` must be some number-type, too. So it would by wrong to add `.length`, in any language.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with C#, but technically you should be able to convert your arrays to a JSON formatted string in C# and then parse this string in JavaScript with `JSON.parse(arr1)`. Also, you don't need the single quotes in `myFunction('" + count + "'`, since count is supposed to be a number, not a string.

Comment: if ```cnt``` is a number, which now makes sense, if OP puts ```var``` before i at the start it should work, however based on the answer below, it looks as if my interpretation of the question is way off

Comment: cnt is the array length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to call a javascript function with string arrays

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"Javascript", "<script type='text/javascript'>myFunction('" + count + "','[" +string.Join(",", array1) + "]','[" + string.Join(",", array2)+ "]');</script>");
```

nb  : you can save the scripts tag via :

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"Javascript", "myFunction('" + count + "','[" +string.Join(",", array1) + "]','[" + string.Join(",", array2)+ "]');",true);
```

Also , you're adding the same key again and again ( "Javascript") :

try adding guid :

`"Javascript"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n")`

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage javascript's apply method here and use *arguments* variable and treat it as the source of your array thereby avoiding messy 'args' on your method. You can then pass a string like:

```
 //After ensuring all elements in array1 are wrapped in ' characters or are appropriate as arguments as-is
 "myFunction.apply(this, [" + array1.join(",") + "])".
```

This way "myFunction" will handle ANY number of arguments or (using the javascript arguments object) array of any size. No need to pass 'count' variable. myFunction will could then be written as:

```
 function myFunction() {
     for (var j = 0, len = arguments.length; j < len; j++) {
         var a = arguments[j];
         //do something with a
     } 
 }
```